# How to merge elements by keys in array in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want merge element with same `["content"]["system.id"]`. This merge contain a list of timestamp (key). We need keep order of timestamp.

in a sample, `["content"]["system.id"]` = 123456789

and the list of timestamp in order is `1693217400000`, `1693217450000`, `1693217500000` and `1693217550000`

init of my code is:

```
products = []
for item in data:
    products.append(item)
    ...
```

**input source:**

```
products = [
    {
      "name":"aaa",
      "date":1693217443241,
      "content":{
        "system.id":"123456789",
        "communication.id":"99",
        "message.id":"b0fa2",
        "1693217400000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        },
        "1693217500000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name":"aaa",
      "date":1693217443241,
      "content":{
        "system.id":"000000001",
        "communication.id":"99",
        "message.id":"b0fa2",
        "1693217400000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        },
        "1693217500000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name":"aaa",
      "date":1693217443241,
      "content":{
        "system.id":"123456789",
        "communication.id":"99",
        "message.id":"b0fa2",
        "1693217450000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"1"
        },
        "1693217550000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        }
      }
    }
]
```

**output:**

```
products = [
    {
      "name":"aaa",
      "date":1693217443241,
      "content":{
        "system.id":"123456789",
        "communication.id":"99",
        "message.id":"b0fa2",
        "1693217400000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        },
        "1693217450000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"1"
        },
        "1693217500000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        },
        "1693217550000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name":"aaa",
      "date":1693217443241,
      "content":{
        "system.id":"000000001",
        "communication.id":"99",
        "message.id":"b0fa2",
        "1693217400000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        },
        "1693217500000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        }
      }
    }
]
```

Comment: what is `data`?

Comment: `data` is no important

Comment: @StéphaneGRILLON, in your output timestamps are just dict keys, that's different from a  list of sorted timestamps. That won't be reliable.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, please read answer of Andrej Kesely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
products = [
    {
        "name": "aaa",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217400000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
            "1693217500000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "aaa",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "000000001",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217400000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
            "1693217500000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "aaa",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217450000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "1"},
            "1693217550000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
        },
    },
]

from functools import reduce

tmp = {}
for p in products:
    tmp.setdefault(p["content"]["system.id"], []).append(p)


def keyfn(t):
    try:
        k = int(t[0])
        return (True, k)
    except:
        return (False,)


out = []
for k, v in tmp.items():
    v[0]["content"] = reduce(lambda a, b: {**a, **b}, (d["content"] for d in v))
    v[0]["content"] = dict(sorted(v[0]["content"].items(), key=keyfn))
    out.append(v[0])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "name": "aaa",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "123456789",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217400000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
            "1693217450000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "1"},
            "1693217500000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
            "1693217550000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "aaa",
        "date": 1693217443241,
        "content": {
            "system.id": "000000001",
            "communication.id": "99",
            "message.id": "b0fa2",
            "1693217400000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
            "1693217500000": {"c1": "0", "c2": "0"},
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
data = [
    {
      "name":"aaa",
      "date":1693217443241,
      "content":{
        "system.id":"123456789",
        "communication.id":"99",
        "message.id":"b0fa2",
        "1693217400000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        },
        "1693217500000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name":"aaa",
      "date":1693217443241,
      "content":{
        "system.id":"000000001",
        "communication.id":"99",
        "message.id":"b0fa2",
        "1693217400000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        },
        "1693217500000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name":"aaa",
      "date":1693217443241,
      "content":{
        "system.id":"123456789",
        "communication.id":"99",
        "message.id":"b0fa2",
        "1693217450000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"1"
        },
        "1693217550000":{
          "c1":"0",
          "c2":"0"
        }
      }
    }
]

# Initialize a dictionary to store merged items
merged_products = {}

for item in data:
    system_id = item["content"]["system.id"]
    if system_id in merged_products:
        existing_item = merged_products[system_id]
        existing_content = existing_item["content"]
        item_content = item["content"]
        for timestamp_key in item_content:
            if isinstance(timestamp_key, int):
                existing_content[timestamp_key] = item_content[timestamp_key]
    else:
        merged_products[system_id] = item

# Extract the merged items as a list
merged_products_list = list(merged_products.values())

print(merged_products_list)
```

output:

```
[{
    'name': 'aaa',
    'date': 1693217443241,
    'content': {
        'system.id': '123456789',
        'communication.id': '99',
        'message.id': 'b0fa2',
        '1693217400000': {
            'c1': '0',
            'c2': '0'
        },
        '1693217500000': {
            'c1': '0',
            'c2': '0'
        }
    }
}, {
    'name': 'aaa',
    'date': 1693217443241,
    'content': {
        'system.id': '000000001',
        'communication.id': '99',
        'message.id': 'b0fa2',
        '1693217400000': {
            'c1': '0',
            'c2': '0'
        },
        '1693217500000': {
            'c1': '0',
            'c2': '0'
        }
    }
}]
```